# Diagnosing plugin conflicts

Tags: plugins

I'm having problems with what I think are conflicting plugins. I've done my research and I'm a bit stuck.

This conflict only seems to happen *a little while* after a core or a plugin update. Not immediately, but often around 12 hours later.

What happens is the backend stops responding, whilst the front end appears to work, thanks to the cache. If I disable and then re-enable the plugins (via the db) the site responds again and remains stable until the next update.

So, do you have any ideas how I can diagnose what's causing this? Or are there any known conflicts in this list?

The site has these plugins and uses a modified Thematic theme

- Akismet
- BackWPup
- Custom Post Widget
- Display widgets
- Google Analytics Dashboard
- Google Analytics graph integration.
- Gravity Forms
- Maintenance Mode
- NextGEN Gallery
- PHP Snippets
- qTranslate
- TinyMCE Advanced
- WordPress Ken Burns Slideshow
- WP Remote
- WP Super Cache

Thanks in advance

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your file-server have an error log in the WP Directory? I would start by turning on the DeBug and error reporting via the wp-config file. Open your wp-config and add this from the [WordPress Codex Debugging page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) if it's not already there:

```
    // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);

    // Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

    // Disable display of errors and warnings 
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set('display_errors',0);

    // Use dev versions of core JS and CSS file
    define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

It should generate an error log and a debug log that may help locate the issue. It sounds like it takes a while for the issue to show up so disabling plugins one at a time might be a long solution. I'd start with the Maintenance Mode, and the BackWPup plugins and go from there.

Comment: That's great. I didn't realise you could log the errors without echoing them to the user. There's no error log in my WP directory, so I'll turn in on in wp-config like you suggest and give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Jeremy - would you say this is okay to run on a production site? Is it likely to cause a big performance drop?

Comment: It shouldn't create a "big" performance drop, but it will cause more work on your server. If you have plenty of bandwith and processor speed you won't notice a difference. If you are already borderline on either, it could cause a noticeable change in performance. I'd be sure to monitor it closely at first.

Comment: Also, if you're using the DeBug feature you might consider using: `if ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '1' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);` 
`} elseif ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '2' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

`} elseif ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '3' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
}` instead of   `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. You can then see the errors by adding ?debug=1, or ?debug=2, or ?debug=3 to the end of the current pages URL.